# GLX doesn't work using xvfb-run

Tags: ubuntu, x11, graphics, opengl, xvfb

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, and using it through ssh, which means I don't have local GUI for it.

I need to run some command that requires GLX, but things aren't going well.

```
Xvfb :80 -screen 0 1400x900x24 -ac +extension GLX +render -noreset
```

If I execute the above, it says `Initializing built-in extension GLX`. And using `vglrun`(VirtualGL) targeting that(:80) as a 3D X server, I can see `xdpyinfo` says that GLX is there, although actually trying to use GLX ends with an error maybe because it cannot be a real 3D X server?

But if I do the following, there is no GLX (and of course GLX doesn't work when I replace `xdpyinfo` with my command):

```
xvfb-run -a -n 55 -s "-screen 0 1400x900x24 -ac +extension GLX +render -noreset" xdpyinfo
```

Am I understanding them in a wrong way?

Could someone please help me? I really need to use `xvfb-run`...

Thanks!!

**UPDATE**: I tried -e option for `xvfb-run`, and confirmed that it also prints `Initializing built-in extension GLX`. But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your Ubuntu installation misses some OpenGL/GLX packages to be able to use GLX. You can try to install mesa-utils (OpenGL in the dependencies) and run glxgears and glxinfo to test it.